# background image url does not work in my angular project

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to put an image as background image of my site but it does not work here is what I put in my css:

```
.background {
    background: url(assets/images/Forgot_password_2.PNG);
    /*background-color: black;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and here is the error I get:

> ERROR in
>   ./src/app/components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component.css
>   Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
>   C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projet angular
>   8\f-g-habilitation\src\app\components\forgot-password\forgot-password.component.css:2:21:
>   Can't resolve 'assets/images/Forgot_password_2.PNG' in
>   'C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projet angular
>   8\f-g-habilitation\src\app\components\forgot-password'
>
> 1 | .background {
>
> > 2 |     background: url(assets/images/Forgot_password_2.PNG);
> >         |                     ^   3 |     /*background-color: black;*/   4 |     width: 100%;

and here is the architecture of my files:

[image: architecture files]

I have already tried the solutions that were mentioned here (as removed on ../) but it does not work: [Angular 6 error: CSSSyntaxError - Failed to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419646/angular-6-error-csssyntaxerror-failed-to-compile)

can some one help me please ??

Comment: shouldn't the url be a string , `background: url("assets/images/Forgot_password_2.PNG");`

Comment: it's background-image and you missed the quotes '':  background-image: url('path_to_the_image');

Comment: It works to me by `background: url('/assets/images/Forgot_password_2.PNG');`

Comment: hello I have already tried with the " " and the ' ' but it also does not work

Comment: Your image file has an extra space in its file name (before the file extension and after the `2`).

Answer (score 5):

This has been an angular issue for a while, but there is a workaround.

Webpack will not check an image url starting with `^`. For example:

```
background: url("^assets/images/Forgot_password_2.PNG");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the assets folder on you angular.json file? If not, I'll leave a [link](https://lukasznojek.com/blog/2019/03/angular-cli-different-ways-to-include-assets/) with different ways to do it. Cheers.

Comment: are you talking about this little code:  "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/images"
            ], if yes, then yes i added it in my angular.js but it still does not work